# Equivalent Chapel functionality for C fgets function

Tags: io, chapel

What is some Chapel code that is equivalent to C's fgets function?

```
`fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)`
```

The above call to `fgets` reads data from stdin until a newline character is encountered.  The Chapel `readln` function stops reading when whitespace is encountered.  I want `readln` to read until a newline character is encountered.  There is `iostringformat.toend` that appears to be the solution, but how do I get `stdin` to behave as if that is enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Use `readline` instead of `readln`. See https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.channel.readline

Try this program for example:

```
config const fname = "test.txt";
var r = openreader(fname);
var line:string;
while r.readline(line) {
  write("I just read: ", line);
}
```

Comment: We should probably make the documentation for readln point out the other method, anybody want to make a documentation update PR to do so?